# Эффект перехода между страницами

Tags: веб-программирование, html

Почему не работает этот тег?

```
<meta http-equiv ="Page-Enter" Content="RevealTrans(Duration=2.0, Transition=23)">
```

Нашел в сети инфу, что он должен осуществлять эффект переходов между страницами, но, как заставить его работать, не знаю, хелп!

Answer (score 3):

[[@Ольга Янго](/users/22709/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE)](/users/22709/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE), проблема в том, что это проприетарное свойство, которое раньше работало только в IE (на момент упоминания этого свойства — в IE 4+ версии).
Оно не входило ни в один стандарт и служило своего рода расширением для презентаций.

**[The RevealTrans HTML Meta Tag](http://www.influentialcomputers.co.uk/meta-reveal-demo.asp)**
**[Обсуждение на bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/154705-revealtrans-html-meta-tag)**

Comment: Спасибо за такой исчерпывающий ответ!